# demonstrate if postsharp is working with state-machine methods

Tags: c#, postsharp

I'm working for 3 months in a company that's using the postsharp free edition in a project.

However, the project has several state-machine methods (methods with async and others with some linq queries) using custom aspects wihtout "ApplyToStateMachine" configuration and the developers were ignoring the warnings.

The free edition only allows the use of "ApplyToStateMachine" in 10 classes per project, however there are more in the project.

I need to demonstrate the problems this can create to convince the boss to buy postsharp licenses. Is there some demonstration project or some directions to follow to illustrate the problem the aspects have with state machine methods ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

It should be not hard to convince him, just show him this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wrapper();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void Wrapper() {
        try {
            await Test();
        }
        catch {
            Console.WriteLine("exception caught");
        }
    }

    [MyAspect]
    static async Task Test() {
        Console.WriteLine("started");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("second part");
        throw new Exception("exception");
    }
}

[PSerializable]
class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnEntry");
    }

    public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnSuccess({0})", args.ReturnValue);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnExit");
    }

    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnException({0})", args.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

It outputs the following:

```
OnEntry
started
OnSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult])
OnExit
second part
exception caught
```

What we can see? Of 4 aspect methods we override only one works correctly - `OnEntry`.

`OnSuccess` is executed too early, when first part of our async method finishes (so, just before first await). Even more - it's wrong, because method has thrown an exception.

`OnExit` called to early too (obviously).

`OnException` is not called at all, despite method has thrown an exception.

So, almost everything is broken and not works as expected, not sure how it can be usable at all, because any reasonable aspect, even simple like logging or measuring execution time are either broken or (which is much worse) produce incorrect results.

If we set `ApplyToStateMachine` it will produce correct output:

```
OnEntry
started
second part
OnException(exception)
OnExit
exception caught
```